# Javascript ignoring if statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

today i ran into a problem that i don't really know how to solve. Never happened this to me and i don't know the reason why is happening.

```
  function createNodePoints(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         // commented line
        var node = array[i].row[0];
        var c = L.circleMarker([node.lat, node.lon],
            {
                radius: 7,
                color: '#FF0000',
                fill: true,
                fillColor: '#FF0000'

            }
        );
        conditionalLayer.addLayer(c);

        fListener(c, node, new L.LatLng(node.lat, node.lon), false);

        if(i == array.length -1 ){
            console.log("Something");
        }
    }
}
```

I have this piece of code inside a function, and the if statement , which should be executed in the last for-loop iteration, is never executed. If i comment the code between the commented line and the if statement, it executes the if.

The array length is about 30000 and this function is inside an asynchronous call , in case it has to do with that. 
Any help ?

Comment: Is the loop completing?  With 30,000 items it might take a while.

Comment: it takes time to process an array with 30000 elements.

Comment: As above, how long does a single iteration take? Of course if you comment out the code that creates new objects, etc (massively speeding up the loop), it will complete much faster than in your normal use case. Consider also if `conditionalLayer` and `fListener` support 30,000 markers and listeners as well

Comment: I think its not completing. Whats strange is that this used to complete it.

Comment: @RuiBessa open the console and see what it says, a 30000 items is not THAT big that would cause this type of issue honestly

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the code and make sure that the loop is executing correctly. I suspect it may be hanging on one of the calls inside.  Alternatively, it might just be very slow but stepping through the code will identify that.  Check this (for Chrome only - Google for other browsers)... https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @Dellirium The console is not printing a single error , but when opening the verbose tab inside the console, it shows this : "[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 75ms"

Comment: Those "violation" warnings can usually be ignored.  It's only notifying you that "sir, you have an opportunity to speed up your script".  It's only violating some guideline metric determined by Google, not a spec or standard or anything "important".

Comment: Try changing your condition to `if (i % 100 === 0) { console.log("something " + i); }`.  It will print a message every 100 iterations.  If your issue is performance, this will make it easier to see.  (Maybe change it to 1000, too)

Comment: I tested with `var L = {
  constructor(){},
  circleMarker(){},
  LatLng: class { constructor(){} }
}
var conditionalLayer = { addLayer() {} }
function fListener() {}
var array = []

for(var i=0; i<3000000; i++) { array.push({row:[{lat:i,lon:i}]}); }
` and it came back with `Something`. Suspect one of your functions is not returning. (sorry code in comments are so terrible)

Comment: @keithpjolley in situations like this, its helpful to also include a gist of the code in the comment.  It's frowned on for questions/answers, but in comments it's frequently unavoidable and very helpful.

Comment: There is not apparent reason for the condition in this case. Just continue after the loop is done.

Comment: Still not able to do what i want :/ . If remove like 200 positions from the array it works, but with the whole array i cant make it work.

Comment: So , after spending some time debugging , i noticed that the loop is broken on the iteration number 28923 . Always on this position. Even if i start the loop on this position , which runes less code that if it started on i = 0, it breaks. And the console gives me no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out what the problem was. Was an undefined value. It was breaking at a certain point and i couldn't discover the reason since it was not printing on the console the error. 
Thanks to everyone that spend time of their own trying to help me.